# MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText) Polygon coordinates not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, wordpress, coordinates

I am building an airbnb-like map system;

1. I am using Google maps and map.getBounds() to get the coordinates of the visible map area
2. I'm then using these coordinates to create a polygon (see below) that is used to make a search on the table `om_offices_2` coordinates column.
3. post_id is returned (I then grab data from WordPress using this ID)

However the entries returned are inconsistent. It seems fine when zoomed in, but less consistent when the map is zoomed out.

I have the following data stored in the table `om_offices_2`;

(there are other columns, I've removed for ease here)

| post_id | coordinates |
| --- | --- |
| 5665 | POINT(54.8726203 -1.5834213) |
| 5670 | POINT(51.5072178 -0.1275862) |
| 5671 | POINT(34.0549076 -118.242643) |
| 6066 | POINT(-25.267257264196 133.86886311182) |

The following returns A, B & C as expected.

```
SELECT post_id FROM om_offices_2
    WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((
         73.335891622515 -123.06100216909, 
         -29.204445033493 -123.06100216909, 
         -29.204445033493 10.70852908091, 
         73.335891622515 10.70852908091,
         73.335891622515 -123.06100216909))', 4326), coordinates)
```

When I zoom out and make this request, D is returned (and D is not even visible on the map)

```
SELECT post_id FROM om_offices_2
    WHERE MBRContains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((
         84.000596900924 -156.19576779409, 
         -73.963342127533 -156.19576779409, 
         -73.963342127533 111.34329470591, 
         84.000596900924 111.34329470591,
         84.000596900924 -156.19576779409))', 4326), coordinates)
```

Here is how the table is created;

```
"CREATE TABLE om_offices_2 (
                post_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                coordinates POINT NOT NULL SRID 4326,
                bu VARCHAR(255),
                sectors VARCHAR(255),
                cont VARCHAR(255),
                SPATIAL INDEX(coordinates)
            )
```

Here's how the data is stored

```
"INSERT INTO om_offices_2 (post_id, coordinates, bu, sectors, cont)
        VALUES ($post_id, ST_SRID(POINT($longitude, $latitude),4326), '$bu', '$sectors', '$cont')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            coordinates = ST_SRID(POINT($longitude, $latitude),4326),
            bu = '$bu',
            sectors ='$sectors',
            cont = '$cont';"
```

When I use a tool like https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/ to map the coordinates being passed via the mysql statement, the polygon looks right.